# Include millisecond data in JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I have a requirement to send the current system date to microservices on search. The time should include milliseconds information as well. For now I was sending `new Date()` for the same and it looked like:

```
Thu Aug 31 2017 15:06:37 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

However I need the milliseconds information as well so the time should look like:

```
Thu Aug 31 2017 15:06:37.228 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Here 228 is the millisecond at that moment that I can extract using `getMilliseconds()` method of `date`. The question is how can I add this in the date so that it works for all locations wherever the application is accessed?

Comment: You're just seeing one of many possible string interpretations of the `Date` object. I suggest using [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) for data transfer

Comment: You could also send the milliseconds from the epoch and timezone information which would be something easily parseable on any backend platform etc.

Comment: @Phil If I use toISOString() the date looks like 2017-09-12T04:37:09.794Z, how will my microservice convert the Z to timezone?

Comment: @pate could you please share sample code?

Comment: @Manu do you actually need the user's timezone? If so, you can separately send the offset via [`Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset). Timezones / offsets are really only required when **displaying** a date/time instant

Comment: Keep in mind that `2017-08-31T15:06:37.228+05:30` and `2017-08-31T09:36:37.228Z` are the **exact same time**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind having the result as a string, this will show the output you are looking for:

```js
// ES5
var fmtDateMsES5 = function(date) {
  var splitDate = date.toString().split(' ');
  splitDate[4] = splitDate[4] + '.' + date.getMilliseconds();
  return splitDate.join(' ');
}

// log output (ES5)
console.log('ES5 output\n', fmtDateMsES5(new Date()));


// ES6
const fmtDateMsES6 = date => {
  const splitDate = date.toString().split(' ');
  splitDate[4] = `${splitDate[4]}.${date.getMilliseconds()}`;
  return splitDate.join(' ');
};

// log output (ES6)
console.log('ES6 output\n', fmtDateMsES6(new Date()));


// ES5 and ES6 functions logged simultaneously
console.log(
  `\nES5 and ES6 functions logged simultaneously`,
  `\n${'-'.repeat(55)}`,
  `\nES5 output ${fmtDateMsES5(new Date())}`,
  `\nES6 output ${fmtDateMsES6(new Date())}`
);
```

Comment: Thanks much, its very near to the expected result. I tried your code and got Tue,Sep,12,2017,10:47:12.421,GMT+0530,(India,Standard,Time). The problem is that every space is being used as delimiter hence the timezone got destructured..Join is not working.. Its not joining with spaces.

Comment: My bad, the result of this join is a string so I got to assign the same to some other variable or return this.

Comment: No problem. For the purposes of clarity I put the code into a snippet.

Comment: Hey, why does the time in ES5 and ES6 are not exactly same? Difference of .001 milliseconds. Dis you notice?

Comment: It's because they are outputting the time at runtime. The functions are being executed separately, not simultaneously. Therefore, each of them log the `new Date()` at the time each of them are run. We could also log them at the same time in the same `console.log` statement.

Comment: I updated the snippet again to demonstrate the runtime output.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I saw the format method on the Date object but this is not built-in and requires a library.

If you must use a time library I would recommend the excellent [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) and use the "[SSS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)" syntax to get the milliseconds, for example:

```
var now = moment().format('MMM DD h:mm.SSS A');
//Sep 12 8:21.167 AM
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kLL2eobh/